# How do I pass data from Service to Activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-service

Beginner warning although CS student

I have a Service named RestApiService and an activity named MainActivity.

I have a token which I got stored in RestApiService.

In link is screenshot of the RestApiService in imgur
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEboh.jpg

I only find tutorials in Java and I can´t translate.

How do I get it from there to MainActivity? TIA

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is by using some database, store it there and then you can just observe the database on MainAcitivty level to get that value once its available.

An alternative would be to use shared preferences liveData which you will observe on MainActivity again but I guess that's a bit trickier

I would go with creating an entity which you will save in database using Room and then use a ViewModel component to expose liveData to the MainActivity

Comment: These are really over complicated ways of doing it.  Especially involving a database, but even live data here is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way-  bind to the service, and define a Binder for the service with a function to get the value.  Then you can just call that function to get the token.  The Binder is returned to the Activity as the return from bindService().

Here's Google's example of doing so in kotlin:  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#kotlin

Comment: We ended up managing to get it done with SharedPreferences, although maybe not recommended for production

Answer (score 0):

BroadCastReceiver will help you, in your service send a broadcast  intent and in your activity you will receive your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Local BroadcastReceiver` for sending data from service to Activity

Please try this code in your `RestApiService` class where you get token:

```
val intent = Intent("RestApiData")
intent.putExtra("token", myToken)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

In above code `"RestApiData"` is main key of broadcast receiver that you need for getting data in activity, `"token"` is key for myToken value

In Your `MainActivity` class use below code in `onCreate` method:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(tokenPassingReceiver, IntentFilter("RestApiData"))
```

Now use below code outside the onCreate method of activity:

```
 private val tokenPassingReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val bundle = intent.extras
            if (bundle != null) {
                if (bundle.containsKey("token")) {
                    val tokenData = bundle.getString("token")
                    Log.e("MainActivity--","token--$tokenData")

                }
            }
        }
 }
```

For more information check this link: [Kotlin Android Broadcast Intents and Broadcast Receivers](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Kotlin_Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers)

I hope it may help you.

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager is deprecated. Is there any other way?

Comment: same remark, localbroadcastmanager is now deprecated